# Google Search confusing me for my website

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search

I have created new website before 2 weeks and submitted to Google Webmaster Tools. Everything looks fine for me in Webmaster Tools but when I search my site in Google for `site:thesoftwaretesting.com`, as first result it shows something like:

> Try Google Search Console
>
> www.google.com/webmasters/ Do you own thesoftwaretesting.com? Get
>   indexing and ranking data from Google.

Then after from second results it shows my site pages. So, is that any my mistake in Webmaster Tools submission? And because of that it is showing above as first result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just an ad. Google apparently does not check to see if you already have a Google Webmasters Tools account before displaying the ad. I see this all the time for my site. Nothing to worry about.